# SVG to Canvas with Canvg - line filled in and background lines dropped?

Tags: canvas, svg, canvg

I am attempting to convert a SVG to Canvas using [Canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg). Right out of the box is pretty good.

Original SVG Graph
[image: SVG Graph]

Canvas Render
[image: Canvas Render]

I am having a hard time figuring out:

1. Why is the line "getting filled in"? It appears that a line is being drawn from the first point to the last point, but I can't seem to find it in the canvg library.
2. The background line elements are getting dropped: Here is an example `<line class="tick" y2="-220" x2="0"></line>`

Anyone have any ideas? Happy to provide more info. Thanks!

Comment: On your path or polyline element that draws your chart data lines--do you have: fill="none" ?

Comment: Yes. the CSS is `fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-opacity: .25; shape-rendering: crispEdges;` ... however removing `fill:none;` does not fix it. Other ideas? Thanks @markE!

Comment: Could you jsFiddle your code for me to look at?

Answer (score 0):

How do you apply your css styles? Does your svg have multiple classes?
Those won't work properly in canvg, see this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/canvg/issues/detail?id=127

And the quick fix I attached (not tested very well)

```
// @ line 736, replace with:
// add class styles
if (this.attribute('class').hasValue()) {

  // check for multiple classes
  // (<circle class="big green">)
  // with css .big.green {fill:green;r:big;}

  // we dont assume the elements in svg.Styles are sorted, so we check
  // .big.green and .green.big
  // TODO: if its sorted, one could reduce the work done here..

  // generates all possible combination, no doublicates, but taking ordering into account
  // comb2(['aa','bb', 'cc'])
  // [".aa", ".aa.bb", ".aa.bb.cc", ".aa.cc", ".aa.cc.bb", ".bb", ".bb.aa", ".bb.aa.cc", ".bb.cc", ".bb.cc.aa", ".cc", ".cc.aa", ".cc.aa.bb", ".cc.bb", ".cc.bb.aa"]
  var comb2 = function combinations(arr) {
    var fn = function(active, rest, all) {
      if (active != ''){all.push(active);}
      for (var i=0; i<rest.length;++i){
        fn(active + '.'+rest[i], [].concat(rest.slice(0,i), rest.slice(i+1)), all);
      }
      return all;
    }
    return fn('', arr, []);
  }

  var classes = svg.compressSpaces(this.attribute('class').value).split(' ');

  classes = comb2(classes);

  for (var j=0; j<classes.length; j++) {
    styles = svg.Styles[classes[j]];
    if (styles != null) {
      for (var name in styles) {
        this.styles[name] = styles[name];
      }
    }
    styles = svg.Styles[node.nodeName+classes[j]];
    if (styles != null) {
      for (var name in styles) {
        this.styles[name] = styles[name];
      }
    }
  }
}
```